# Sigma-Algebra Making Random-variable Random

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a complete probability space, $E$ be an uncountable set, and $X:\Omega \rightarrow E$ be a function.  Is there a finest (non-trivial) topology on $E$ making $X$ a Borel-measurable random variable?

Comment: Why add non-trivial? The finest topology on $E$ is the discrete one and maybe for some cases it is the finest such topology? Or do you want to rule out the indiscrete topology?

Comment: It could well be false (I think) but also hard to prove false...

Comment: I wanted to rule out the indiscrete topology.  This is what I use but I was curious if one could "do better".

Comment: As $X$ is Borel-measurable random variable we have $\mathcal F=\{X^{-1}(B)\mid B \subseteq E \}$ and take  the underlying topological structure.

Comment: We did not asume that X is not hotel measurable but instead are looking for the strongest topology making it Hotel measurable.  Please read the question

Comment: I studied probability theory more than twenty years ago, so I can miss something. But can we do the following? For each point $x\in X(\Omega)$ let $\tau_x$ be a topology on the set $E$ in which all points of a set $\{x\}\cup E\setminus  X(\Omega)$ are isolated and a set $X(\Omega)\setminus \{x\}$ is closed and open with the induced antidisrete topology. If each of topologies $\tau_x$ makes $X$ a Borel-measurable random variable, and there exists the finest topology $\tau_f$, which makes $X$ a Borel-measurable random variable then $\tau_x\subset\tau_f$ for each $x$ thus $\tau_f$ is discrete.